# ListView null pointer exception when accessing rows "lower down" the list

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

So I have a ListView with about 10 rows of data. It renders fine and all, but when I try doing a mListView.getChildAt(index); call, the resulting view is NULL IF it is below and including the 5th row down from the top.

here is where i make the call, a logcat, and a sincere thank you in advance:

```
View r = manageTransfersList.getChildAt(mTaskIndex);
```

where `mTaskIndex` is passed from

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            ...
            mTaskIndex = position;
    ...
}
```

LogCat:

```
08-07 09:15:12.420: E/AndroidRuntime(7657): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 09:15:12.420: E/AndroidRuntime(7657): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 09:15:12.420: E/AndroidRuntime(7657):     at org.globus.globus.transfer.ManageTransfersFragment$TaskDetailsDialogFragment$1.onClick(ManageTransfersFragment.java:469)
08-07 09:15:12.420: E/AndroidRuntime(7657):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
08-07 09:15:12.420: E/AndroidRuntime(7657):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
08-07 09:15:12.420: E/AndroidRuntime(7657):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-07 09:15:12.420: E/AndroidRuntime(7657):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-07 09:15:12.420: E/AndroidRuntime(7657):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-07 09:15:12.420: E/AndroidRuntime(7657):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4896)
08-07 09:15:12.420: E/AndroidRuntime(7657):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 09:15:12.420: E/AndroidRuntime(7657):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-07 09:15:12.420: E/AndroidRuntime(7657):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
08-07 09:15:12.420: E/AndroidRuntime(7657):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
08-07 09:15:12.420: E/AndroidRuntime(7657):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: So you are calling getChildAt() from within onListItemClick()?

Comment: is that Listview or ExpandableListview are used ?

Comment: isn't `v` the `View` you're looking for? Otherwise, maybe you're not using it at the right place. I've been playing around with ListViews, and when it's not easy, then there is another way to do what you want. Ask what you want to do with your ListView!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using, for the data item you want

```
 manageTransfersList.getAdapter().getItem(mTaskIndex);
```

Or if you want the view,  just use the "v" param from your onListItemClick (no need to get the item by adapter or searching by child index)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to go to your list's adapter rather than the list to get the details of an item at position n or the view at position n.

i.e. I have in my project:

IconifiedText text = (IconifiedText) adapter.getItem(position);